# Location coming up as null in Android

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location, android-gps

I have this method that I am calling in the `onCreate()` and `onResume()` methods in my `MainActivity`.

Basically, I'm using it so I can get the city name of my current location and set it to a string so I can use it later.
And to see if it worked I just set it to my welcome text.

The method is:

```
    private void getLocation() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {

                    Location location = task.getResult();
                    if (location != null) {

                        try {
                            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

                            cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality(); // sets the address here
                            Welcome.setText(cityName);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location null error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},44);
        }
    }
```

Thing is, when I'm on the the android studio emulator, it works fine in most cases.

But when I'm running the app on my phone I get the "location null error" toast I have set up.
Meaning location is null. Even when location is turned on in the device settings.

I can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you want to use your geocoder inside the locationupdates method. Once the location is not null use that location to find your address then stop the updates.

For this you need to use requestLocationUpdates because lastKnownlocation could be null if the location was not requested in a certain amount of time by another application.

Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296991/callback-method-onlocationchanged-is-not-working-on-viewmodel/69297614#69297614) in this question. It will help you to get a location by using location updates

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Both emulator and my phone. 
Absolute nightmare to get through, but following your code in the linked post worked perfectly.

I'd give you an upvote but I don't have enough reputation yet. Sorry. :(

Comment: No problem, glad it helped